# Design a two-row tabBar in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt

I am currently designing a tab bar in PyQt6 with python and I want it to be designed in a way that all the tabs  be arranged in two rows insted of one row. To design a tab bar in one row, I use "QTabWidget". but I have no idea how to design a tab bar with two rows.
In addition to what I described earlier, I have demonstrated the output I am seeking for in the following picture.

[image]

```
class TabBarApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("TabBarApp")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 150)
        self.layout2 = QGridLayout()
        self.tabbar = QTabBar()
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad1")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad1")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad1")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad1")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad1")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad2")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad2")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad2")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad2")
        self.tabbar.addTab("dsad2")
        self.fake1 = self.tabbar.addTab("")
        self.tabbar.setTabVisible(self.fake1, False)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabbar)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = TabBarApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```